# Combining ansible tasks to one task with one definition of "changed"

Tags: deployment, compilation, ansible

As part of deployment there is a bit of compilation I want to do on the host. This consists of moving the source files, compiling the program, and removing the source files. I would want it to work in such a way that this results in just `ok` rather than `changed` if the program did not change.

This would accurately describe the situation, because if the program did not change, then by running the playbook a (assumedly) non-existent directory would be created, a command run resulting in some file that's then moved to where a identical copy used to be, and then the source files are removed and the created directory is once again non-existent.

Concretely, the tasks would be something like:

```
- copy:
    src: src/
    dest: /tmp/my_program_src/
- shell: my_compiler -o /usr/local/bin/my_program /tmp/my_program_src/main.file
  become: true
- file:
    path: /tmp/my_program_src/
    state: absent
```

Of course what actually happens is that all three report "changed"; because for shell I would have to define `changed_when` myself, and `copy` as well as `file` change something, though they cancel each other out.

Can I group this together into one task which reports `ok` if `/usr/local/bin/my_program` did not change? If yes, then how? If no, then what would be the 'right' way to do something like this?

Comment: dont see how you have 1 return value from 3 "grouped" tasks. is this for cosmetic purposes?

Comment: "*there is a bit of compilation I want to do on the host*" ー don't compile on the host. Problem disappeared.

Comment: @techraf But do what instead? Delegate compilation to localhost, then copy the result, still in ansible? Or don't compile using ansible at all? One of the reasons for me to do it this way is that in my particular case (raco to compile racket) it is rather problematic to compile using a different version of the software than the one you use to run the program with.

Comment: @ilias-sp I'm mostly just looking for the 'right' way to do things. I regard these three steps as not making sense without one another when it comes to idempotence (or not). But I'd like to know the right way to do it whether that means grouping the tasks or not.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, I recommend doing the Ansible way like this. Other option is generating a script and calling it by `command:`. Then checking the sha1 with Ansible, but I don't like that option.

```
---
- name: Example
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  connection: local

  tasks:

    - name: Get cksum of my program
      stat:
        path : "/usr/local/bin/my_program"
      register: myprogram1

    - name: Current SHA1
      set_fact:
        mp1sha1: "{{ myprogram1.stat.checksum }}"

    - name: Copy File
      copy:
        src: src/
        dest: /tmp/my_program_src/
      changed_when: False

    - name: Compile
      shell: my_compiler -o /usr/local/bin/my_program /tmp/my_program_src/main.file
      become: true
      changed_when: False

    - name: Remove src
      file:
        path: /tmp/my_program_src/
        state: absent
      changed_when: False

    - name: Get cksum of my program
      stat:
        path : "/usr/local/bin/my_program"
      register: myprogram2

    - name: Current SHA1
      set_fact:
        mp2sha1: "{{ myprogram2.stat.checksum }}"

    - name: Compilation Changed
      debug:
        msg: "Check Compilation"
      changed_when:  mp2sha1 == mp1sha1
```